# Why is scala tuple access syntax not easier to type?

Tags: scala

I find myself wanting to avoid tuples just because the access syntax is ugly. Given that the arity is limited, why does Scala not support a nicer syntax the looks better and is easier to type? This is my suggestion:

```
val t = (1,2,3)
// Proposed equivalent reference syntax.
assert(t.a == t._1)
assert(t.b == t._2)
assert(t.c == t._3)
```

So, am I trying to be elegant, or just stupid?

Comment: You can implement it as a library.

Comment: @LimbSoup "You ought to avoid using tuples, anyway." Wat?

Comment: @NikitaVolkov They're ugly creatures, but obviously they have their applications.

Comment: @LimbSoup "They're ugly creatures" Again, WAT?! )

Comment: What's the big difference between `a` and `_1`? Doesn't seem that fundamental to me.

Comment: This is a question for somewhere else, like the scala-debate mailing list.

Comment: I think I remember seeing a historical reason for the naming of `_1`.

Comment: @ErikAllik I can't think of any historical reason, `SML` uses `#n` to access values example: `#2 (3, 12, 19)` returns 12, `Haskell` implements `fst` and `snd` to access the first and second value, `C#` uses `.Item#`, example: `Tuple.Create(3, 12, 19).Item2` would return 12... Every language with tuples implements this differently, so it strikes me as odd that Scala chose to use `._#` for "historical reasons"

Comment: Well I just recently saw something but I'm sure it's not important.

Comment: A lot of the time, it's better to use a case class. Then you can name the fields what you like

Answer (score 5):

Usually you don't need to use the `_1` etc. methods because you can do pattern matching:

```
val t = (1,2,3)
val (a, b, c) = t

val t2 = ((1, 2), (3, 4))
t2 match {
  case ((a, b), (c, d)) if a > c && b > d => true
  case _ => false
}
```

Comment: By this logic if I'm ugly I should avoid looking in the mirror instead of getting that blemish removed ;)